# Expression in field calculator to pick out multiples of x

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I have an attribute table of contours at intervals of 10m but I wish to label the layer at intervals of 50m. My method was to create a new field with an expression which would copy the entries in the parent field (PROP_VALUE) whose value would be a multiple of 50. i.e 50,100,150,200 etc leaving the entry empty (NULL) if not a multiple of 50.

I got somewhere with the CASE expression but QGIS wouldn't let me repeat the expression for 100m, 150, and 200m. I suppose I could update the existing field but there must be a simple/faster way.

[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly for qgis as I don't use it, but there should be a modulo command e.g.  `mod(field, 50)` for multiples of 50 etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to include `CASE` at the beginning and `END` at the end of your expression. So it should read:

```
CASE 
WHEN "PROP_VALUE" IS 50 THEN '50' 
WHEN "PROP_VALUE" IS 100 THEN '100' 
...
END
```

---

As [@Midavalo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64785/midavalo) mentioned, you could also use the modulo operator:

```
CASE WHEN "PROP_VALUE" % 50 = 0 THEN "PROP_VALUE" END
```

Comment: @JamesB - Most welcome and don't worry about it! You should see some of the first questions I asked here ;)